# Why QHeaderView::section:checked and :selected stylesheet doesn't work?

Tags: c++, qt, qtstylesheets

I am trying to create a custom table header style without section separators and with different colors.

I have this in my stylesheet:

```
QHeaderView::section {
    border: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
    background-color: white;
}

QHeaderView::section:hover {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #aaaaaa;
}

QHeaderView::section:selected, QHeaderView::section:checked {
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(0, 166, 228);
    background-color: rgb(255, 170, 0);
}
```

It works except the style for active (clicked) section. I thought it should be either `:checked` or `:selected` pseudo state (which are mentioned in docs http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html) but I don't see any effect.

Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it is not supported by `QHeaderView`, I guess `:checked` and `:selected` are either used for some other purposes or simply not implemented.

Found some old bug reports, reopened one of them: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-23689

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. It works when calling these two methods:

```cpp
horizontalHeader()->setSectionsClickable( true );
horizontalHeader()->setHighlightSections( true );
```

See also this [issue report](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-23689).